# App engine call to Google API python client return 403 with @oauth_required

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

It should be a trivial job but i cannot get it out.

I need to call the Google Calendar API from Gae; thus I set all up as per Google docs and examples:

I've an `/auth.py`:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
]
decorator = appengine.OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(
    filename=CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope=SCOPES,
    cache=memcache,
    prompt='consent',
)
```

called by `main.py` functions:

```
class Landing(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @auth.decorator.oauth_aware
    def get(self):
        if auth.decorator.has_credentials():
            self.redirect('/in')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('''
            etc. {}'''.format(auth.decorator.authorize_url()))

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @auth.decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        links = { ... }
        render(self, 'base.html', template_values=links)

class Calendar(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @auth.decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=auth.decorator.http())
        api_request = service.events().list(calendarId='primary')
        api_response = api_request.execute()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(api_response, indent=4))

class PutEvent(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @auth.decorator.oauth_required
    def post(self):
        # ...
        # http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
        service = build('calendar', 'v3') #, http=http)

        api_response = []
        for i in json.loads(self.request.get('events')):
            # ...
            event = { ... } # Google Calendar event
            api_request = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=scadenza)
            api_response.append(api_request.execute(http=auth.decorator.http()))

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(api_response, indent=4))
```

As you can see this is a fairly simple `post` requested by an Ajax jQuery call (`$.post('{{ putEvent_url }}', jsonData, function( data ){ console.log(data); })`...

I'm in the development server, using `test@example` user, and the app is authorized to access my personal account's Google Calendar.

Strange thing to me is that any **call to Calendar() works as expected, but *call to PutEvent() end in ERROR 500***.

Looking to the end of the traceback in console:

```
  File "/home/pierpaolo/Devnos/whiterabbit/include/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.py", line 644, in check_oauth
    resp = method(request_handler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pierpaolo/Devnos/whiterabbit/main.py", line 211, in post
    api_response.append(api_request.execute(http=auth.decorator.http()))
  File "/home/pierpaolo/Devnos/whiterabbit/include/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pierpaolo/Devnos/whiterabbit/include/googleapiclient/http.py", line 838, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
INFO     2017-01-04 15:13:32,385 module.py:788] default: "POST /api/put/scadenze HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I cannot understand the

**HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Forbidden">**

it looks to me I already granted the app access to my account and that Google App Engine decorators have been correctly put in place to make the OAuth2.0 thing as per https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine...

**EDIT:**
I was wondering if my trouble can be related to the way i call Google Calendar API:

```
     HTML/JS            GAE/Py
+------------------+
|                  |
| <form>           |
|   ...data        |
| <\JS/Ajax        |
|   $.post(...data |  -->  GAE/main.py
|                  |         @auth.decorator.oauth_required
|                  |         def post(self, data):
+------------------+           event = elaborate(data)
                               service = build('calendar', 'v3')
                               api_request = service.events()
                                             .insert(calendarId='primary',
                                                     body=event)
                               api_response = api_request
                                              .execute(auth.decorator
                                                           .http())
                               self.response(api_response)
```

**EDIT 3:**
I looked a bit into oauth2client.contrib.appengine and I added some `logger.debug` here and there: I think the problem could be in `execute(http=decorator.http())` call, but it is the same in my other handlers! Neither positional nor keyword nor put authrized Http in service `build` changes the misbehaviour...

Nor can I see what problem may pose `_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper`...

**Dear all, some hint on how to research further?**

**Actually, I can insert Acl and/or insert a secondary calendar in the same RequestHandler that throws Forbidden exception with events().insert()...!**

Comment: @everyone: The same code works with success for userinfo.profile and calendar (events.list)... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is to try to insert an all-day event with `endTimeUnspecified: True`...

I opened an issue on google-api-python-client GitHub tracker: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/334.

Maybe someone will look into it or post a more precise answer.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got enough reputation to comment so I'll just leave it as an answer:

Firstly, double check that you've got calandar api enabled at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=yourproject

Secondly. I've used the contacts API and discovered that once you've granted access once you cannot be granted access again unless you first revoke the initial allowance. I encountered this when a user connected my app to Google Contacts, then disconnected, then tried to reconnect - the second reconnect would fail. To check / revoke, head to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: Thank you. But i think the reason of the 403 forbidden is somewhat related to the way i call the api: i think i loss the cookie/authorized_http/credential/whatever when i submit my form to python requesthandler then delegate to that function another request that actually call google api with elaborated data. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Absurd: actually, I can insert Acl and/or insert a secondary calendar in the same RequestHandler that throws Forbidden exception with events().insert()...! HOWEVER, I CANNOT INSERT EVENT NEITHER IN THE SECONDARY CALENDAR ADDED BY MY APPENGINE APP!!